# Gitlab CI: job hangs up on cloning repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two job pipeline in our CI process in Gitlab.com CI (with shared runners) and second one hangs up on `Checking out c5b6078f as master...`

First job "build" completes correctly and pushes valid image to AWS docker registry. Second jobs hangs up before even starting on checking repository.

I have tried both git strategies "fetch" and "clone" with same result.

job log:

- Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.5.2 (76fdacd)
- Using Docker executor with image silintl/ecs-deploy ...
- Pulling docker image silintl/ecs-deploy ...
- Running on runner-8a2f473d-project-1459347-concurrent-0 via runner-8a2f473d-machine-1472732000-783cccf8-digital-ocean-4gb...
- Cloning repository...
- Cloning into '/builds/zendoro/frontend-catalogue'...
- Checking out c5b6078f as master...

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: ekino/dind-aws

stages:
  - build
  - deploy-dev
  - deploy-prod

variables:
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: XXXYYYZZZ.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$CI_BUILD_REF
  CONTAINER_TAG: XXXYYYZZZ.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME

build:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - eval $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_IMAGE $CONTAINER_TAG
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TAG

deployment-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  image: silintl/ecs-deploy
  script:
    - ecs-deploy -c default -n $CI_PROJECT_NAME -i $CONTAINER_IMAGE
  environment: Development
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - master

deployment-prod:
  stage: deploy-prod
  image: silintl/ecs-deploy
  script:
    - ecs-deploy -c production -n $CI_PROJECT_NAME -i $CONTAINER_IMAGE
  environment: Production
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - tags
```

I have also tried another image for deployment "jakubriedl/ecs-deploy" which is basically the same but on Alpine linux and it did not hanged up but ended with `ERROR: Build failed: exit code 2`

full job log with alpine image:

- Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.5.2 (76fdacd)
- Using Docker executor with image jakubriedl/ecs-deploy ...
- Pulling docker image jakubriedl/ecs-deploy ...
- Running on runner-8a2f473d-project-1459347-concurrent-0 via runner-8a2f473d-machine-1472734703-4f8bb312-digital-ocean-4gb...
- Cloning repository...
- Cloning into '/builds/zendoro/frontend-catalogue'...
- Checking out 3647bc37 as master...
- ERROR: Build failed: exit code 2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in some sort of bug in GitLab-CI. Image must not have ENTRYPOINT defined because it fails described way. So creating image without ENTRYPOINT is solution.

Related issue on gitlab https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1507

Answer (score 0):

The answer today is more likely to be found in [Overriding Entrypoints Doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#overriding-the-entrypoint-of-an-image) -- the section labeled "For Docker 17.06+".

GitLab can run images with `ENTRYPOINT` defined without issue, provided you override it like `entrypoint: [""]` and then treat it as though you picked the best shell the image is capable of when you write your `script` sections.